# How do I take a screenshot and crop out white space?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, screenshot, uigraphicscontext

I have an app that allows a user to add a photo to their photo and save it kind of like a sticker app.  I have it set up to take a screen shot right now but the problem I am facing is that it takes a screenshot of the entire `UIView` so there is a lot of white space and the `UIButtons` are visible in the final saved photo in the **camera roll**.

How do I take a screen shot that crops out the white space from the app?

Here's what I have right now...

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    self.savedImageAlert()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I have played around with making the bounds equal to the `UIImageview` called userImageView but that made my photo distorted and still had a lot of white space just at the top of the photo instead of the top and the bottom.

I am new to Swift and have a hard time with the **CG/UIGraphics** stuff so any help would be really appreciated...I've spent hours researching this and have been getting more and more confused!

NOTE/UPDATE: I have changed my code to the following:

// I defined myView outside of both functions so that I could reference myView in both the function and the IBAction function

```
   let myView = UIView()
func imageWithView(myView:UIView)->UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

@IBAction func mergeAndSaveImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let newImage = imageWithView(myView)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
    self.savedImageAlert()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

In my storyboard I set up a new `UIView`, renamed it and dragged my two `UIImageViews` underneath it in the document outline.

I am still not able to get this to work, when I save the image it saves the entire screen with white space and `UIbuttons`.

First, I don't want the image with the Detroit notebook to be so small, on the storyboard it's much bigger but when I run the app it gets small in the uiview.

Second, the code just saves an image of the entire screen...I only want the UIView that contains the two uiimages to be saved as an image.

Here's what it saves as....

[Here's what the code saves...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL3Tg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you could manage to add a photo inside some `UIView` then this method can help you. You just have to pass the `UIView` here and for that particular `UIView` only it will return an `UIImage` object. It will not take other screen area but just the `UIView` which you will be passing as a parameter.
So the hierarchy will be like this. There will be a `UIImageView` within a `UIView` and all the other things required for your sticker will be there in your same `UIView` which will be passed in the below method in order to retrieve only the specific bounded UIImage.

That `UIImage` can easily be saved or retrieved anywhere.

```
//function to convert the given UIView into an UIImage
func imageWithView(view:UIView)->UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

and later on You can save only that image where ever you want.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

**EDIT:**
On button click perform this:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // you will get an UIImage object
    let image = imageWithView(yourCustomView)

    //Then save your image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: "When you are done modifying the context, you must call the UIGraphicsEndImageContext function to clean up the bitmap drawing environment and remove the graphics context from the top of the context stack." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, Edited the solution.

Comment: I'm trying to wire it up to an IBAction, previously I had it set up so that when a button was pressed the function was carried out.  I'm having a hard time with it now since it has a return value...how do I handle this?  Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm still new!

Comment: You just have to call this method inside inaction method.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still running into a small problem - right now it still saves all of the white space.  Is it possible that I'm passing the wrong parameter (yourCustomView) in the IBAction Method?  Note: I have the two UIImageViews underneath the UIView in the storyboard (i.e. I dragged them in the document outline so they're staggered underneath the UIView that I dragged onto my view controller.

Comment: @KateOwens What are you passing in the parameter?

Comment: view (in my storyboard I dragged a UIview and changed its name on the document outline to view)

Comment: well, first of all don't change the name to view. Give any other name like myView as view is default name for the superview. Secondly pass this myView in the method. Make sure myView only contains imageViews etc

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.  Should I make the UIImage Views subviews of the UIView?  If so should I do it programmatically or just by dragging them underneath the UIView in the document outline?

Comment: you can drag them in storyboard inside your custom view.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I defined the myView outside of both functions so I can reference and use it in the function that you provided as well as the IBAction function for the button press... still no luck making it save properly...

Comment: let myView = UIView()
func imageWithView(myView:UIView)->UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

@IBAction func mergeAndSaveImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let newImage = imageWithView(myView)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
    self.savedImageAlert()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari code is in comment above this one...sorry about formatting.  This is also visible in my question above; this part of the code is at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Show screenshots please what output you are getting and what actually you want

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I added a screen shot of what gets saved from the app... see my question post.  You'l have to click the link since I can't embed images directly yet.

Comment: @KateOwens And whats the expected image you want?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari the expected image is just the images within the UIView...if you look at the image I linked to in my question it should be only the image without white space from the rest of the screen and without buttons visible.

Comment: actually its really hard to tell which view contains what. Can you give a background color to the view as red or something so that we can recognise whats happening. Provide any color to the view which you are passing in the function

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I made the background of the view blue and it showed up behind the two image views that I dragged underneath the view in the storyboard.  It looks as though the two photos are contained in the blue view...